# splicing a list declared inside an omp_parallel block to a list declared outside the block in openmp C++

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm wondering what happens when one splices a (C++) list declared inside an omp_parallel block to a list declared outside the block. An example would be the following :

```
list<object> l;


#pragma omp parallel
{
    list<object> t;


//  ..each thread creates some objects and adds them to t, then.. 


#pragma omp critical 
{
    l.splice(l.end(),t);
}


}
```

I've tried this and it works just fine, but I'm wondering what is going on underneath. Does the memory for each local list t, which is private for each thread, get re-assigned to "shared" somehow in external list l? Is there any danger in doing this? Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The heap memory is shared anyway, isn't it? So this would be more interesting with lists allocated using a `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` initialized with stack memory, i.e. a `std::array` as buffer.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but I'm confused by the fact that the t-lists are not accessible to the program outside the omp parallel block. So somehow the permission to access the memory space occupied by the t-lists has been passed to the program outside the omp parallel block when operating on the list l. This must be true since C++ splice doesn't create any new memory -- it simply re-assigns the list pointers for l to the memory space that existed for the t-lists before they were spliced.

Comment: Well the list object itself is on the stack but it contains pointers to the heap where the actual elements/nodes reside. But this is just my intuition.

Comment: I would be more concerned for the performance of this, especially on NUMA systems. The nodes of the resulting `l` could be spread over multiple NUMA nodes making later access rather expensive.

Comment: Thanks paleonix, that's what I started thinking just after I sent my last message. Thanks also for the note on NUMA performance .